# Bus Error in 2d array

Tags: c, arrays, unix

I am trying to read in a matrix file where the first 2 lines display the number of rows then columns in the array. After that each line contains 1 double as an entry into that matrix (in row traversal format). I can read in most of the data fine, but I obtain a bus error when I try to obtain the second to last row (8th in a 10x10 or 3rd in a 5x3, etc.)

```
  double input[row1-1][col1-1];
  char buffer[50];
  int i, j;
  for(i = 0; i < row1; i++)
  {
    for(j = 0; j < col1; j++)
  {
    if(fgets(buffer, 50, f1) == NULL)
      printf("error \n");
    else 
    {
      input[i][j] = atof(buffer);
      printf("%f ", input[i][j]);
    }
  buffer[0] = '\0';
  }
printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: double input[row1-1][col1-1];
 should be   double input[row1][col1];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your array indexes will only go from `0..row1-1` and `0..col1-1`, the array dimensions must be `row1` and `col1`:

```
double input[row1][col1];
```

Answer (score 1):

The input array is declared to have row1 - 1 rows. So they are numbered from 0 to row1 - 2. You are iterating from 0 to row1 - 1. So the last access is out of bounds. Same problem with the columns.

I think you actually want the first line to be `input[row1][col1]`.